# Cannot Get The Correct Line Position Using Stretch=Fill in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I have a canvas that has 3 lines of the same points.

- My first line (Red Line) has correct position.
- However my second (Green line) and third line (Blue Line) are not plotted the same location of my red line when using `Stretch="Fill"`.

I need to use `Stretch="Fill"` since my app should have drag/resize/rotate functionality. Please help.

Based on my code below how can I align either the green or blue line to have position same with my red line? I need to use ContentControl since the sample drag/resize/rotate is using this.

#### XAML

```
<Canvas Name="canvas" Background="White" Opacity="99">
    <Line X1="244" X2="244" Y1="50" Y2="200" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="10"/>
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Line X1="244" X2="244" Y1="50" Y2="200" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="10" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Canvas.Left="244" Canvas.Top="50">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Line X1="244" X2="244" Y1="50" Y2="200" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="10" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
</Canvas>
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Output screenshot]

Comment: Remove stretch, canvas.left, and canvas.right property

Comment: Hi @VimalCK based on my requirements I need to use Stretch="Fill". This will be used in drag/resize/rotate. Without Stretch the line width will remain as is whenever I do the resize/rotate.

Comment: Then set Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top same for all the content controls

Comment: Hi @vimal, my problem is that putting line inside a contentcontrol has some extra points. Look at the case of red and blue lines. They should overlap and should be in the same coordinates but it seems the blue line has extra x and y points.